# How to get value from Reverse()?

Tags: rust

I'm trying MinHeap from std::BinaryHeap like

```
use std::collections::BinaryHeap;
use std::cmp::Reverse;

let mut heap = BinaryHeap::new();

heap.push(Reverse(1));
heap.push(Reverse(5));
heap.push(Reverse(2));

assert_eq!(heap.pop(), Some(Reverse(1)));
assert_eq!(heap.pop(), Some(Reverse(2)));
assert_eq!(heap.pop(), Some(Reverse(5)));
assert_eq!(heap.pop(), None);
```

But allow varibles from heap.pop() or heap.peek() is Reverse() type, which is not easy to use, how to get value from it?

Answer (score 2):

From [the docs](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/cmp/struct.Reverse.html) we can see that `Reverse` is a tuple and its only field is public:

```
pub struct Reverse<T>(pub T);
```

This means we can access the field with `.0` Like this:

```
let reversed = Reverse(42);
assert_eq!(reversed.0, 42);
```

Comment: You can also use destructuring: `let reversed = Reverse(42); let Reversed(n) = reversed; assert_eq!(n, 42);`.